# How to calculate a module's dist hash

Tags: raku, zef

I have Raku installed in `~/.rakudo-star/rakudo-star-2018.04`, using LoneStar. When `zef` installs a module, it gets installed into a subdirectory of the Rakudo directory. In here is a directory named `perl6/site/resources`, which seem to hold all the installed files. How can I figure out which module is contained in which file, using Raku?

Comment: The sha1s are an implementation detail. Also see https://github.com/ugexe/zef/issues/241#issuecomment-383823558 — “The on-disk layout of the a CompUnit::Repository::Installation is undocumented and may change at any time.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you shouldn't. It's [zef](https://github.com/ugexe/zef) the one that must take care of it. But if you positively have to, use the SHA1 signatures in the directory with `zef locate`

```
zef --sha1 locate 5417D0588AE3C30CF7F84DA87D27D4521713522A
```

will output (in my system)

```
===> From Distribution: zef:ver<0.4.4>:auth<github:ugexe>:api<>
lib/Zef/Service/Shell/PowerShell/download.pm6 => /home/jmerelo/.rakudobrew/moar-2018.06/install/share/perl6/site/sources/5417D0588AE3C30CF7F84DA87D27D4521713522A
```

From your question, it's not too clear if what you want to do is the opposite, that is, find out which SHA1 corresponds to which file; in that case, try and to this:

```
zef locate bin/lwp-download.pl
```

which will return

```
===> From Distribution: LWP::Simple:ver<0.103>:auth<Cosimo Streppone>:api<>
bin/lwp-download.pl => /home/jmerelo/.rakudobrew/moar-2018.06/install/share/perl6/site/resources/059BD7DBF74D1598B0ACDB48574CC351A3AD16BC
```

Comment: I wanted to do the opposite, for a new functionality in `p6man`. I want to be able to run `p6man Some::Module` and make it render the pod of `Some::Module`

Comment: Also, is there no specific part of zef I can `use` to do this from within Perl 6?

Comment: @Tyil if I remember correctly, I also asked somewhere if the commands in the zef CLI could be used from other programs. Since all of them are codified as MAIN functions, it's kind of hard. Answer was: no, you can't, and it's not in the roadmap. So i guess it's either run it as an external program or fork and try to do that...

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the source of a namespace that would get loaded you can do:

```
my $module-name = 'Test';

# Get a Distribution object which provides an IO interface to its contents
my $compunit         = $*REPO.resolve(CompUnit::DependencySpecification.new(:short-name{$module-name}));
my $distribution     = $compunit.distribution;
my $handle-from-name = $distribution.content($distribution.meta<provides>{$module-name}.keys[0]).open;
say $handle-from-name.slurp(:close);

# Or if we already know the name-path:
my $handle-from-path = $distribution.content("lib/Test.rakumod").open;
say $handle-from-path.slurp(:close);
```

Note that `$compunit.distribution` will only work if resolve returned a CompUnit from a `CompUnit::Repository::Installation` repository.

[rakudo@1812](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/1812) is the framework to improve this further, allowing individual repositories to be queried ( `$*REPO.resolve` iterates the linked list of repos to give a result ) and unifying behavior for resolve/candidates/etc between `CompUnit::Repository::Installation` and `CompUnit::Repository::FileSystem`.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the absolute path to the file in question, instead of an `IO::Handle`?

Comment: Whatever backs a Distribution's content method is an implementation detail -- it might be backed by a file, [socket](https://github.com/ugexe/Perl6-Distribution--Common--Remote/blob/d152ce7ab92794a28856648ba6b177c4130f29ee/t/01-basic.t#L8), data piped from a process, etc. You can technically achieve this *in this specific instance* via `$distribution.content($distribution.meta<provides><Test>.keys[0]).path` but you'd be depending on undocumented/unsupported behavior that we may change at any time.

Comment: Also: since you are trying to extract POD you likely do not need the file itself. The source should suffice for this purpose since you can EVAL it or use something like `my $*LINEPOSCACHE; say Perl6::Grammar.parse($source, :actions(Perl6::Actions.new())).ast.dump;`